# How do installation in linux (Fedora)?

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, compile, make

I'm trying to run an example of [MOBS - Mobile Robot Simulator](http://robotics.ee.uwa.edu.au/mobs/), I'm trying to install the requirements and run the example, but I'm new with linux so don't understand how make these steps :

```
1. XView
   For the User-Interface.
   At least the includes and the xview- and olgx-library!

2. DevGuide
   The Interface-builder. For recompilation, the includes and
   the guide- and guidexv-libraries must be available.
   (set the GUIDEHOME-variable to the devguide-directory)

3. PVM-library
   For communications between differenc processen.

4. OpenInventor (from SGI)
   This is needed for the camera-view-generation.
```

And these:

```
Now set the Env-variable MOBS_HOME and add $MOBS_HOME/bin.$(HOSTTYPE)
and $MOBS_HOME/cmd to your path-variable.

Example commands to add to your '.cshrc'-startup-script if you have
unpack the packages in your home-directory.
...........................................................................
# .cshrc-addition
if (-d ~/mobs) then
    setenv MOBS_HOME ~/mobs
    set path = ( $path $MOBS_HOME/bin.$HOSTTYPE )
endif
...........................................................................


NOTE: The ivd_server use the MOBS_HOME-variable for referencing the
      files in the $MOBS_HOME/iv-directory.

Now add at least the bin-directory in which the ivd_server-program is
located to your .pvm-hosts-file.

Example '.pvm-hosts'-file if you have a SGI namend 'munch' and a SUN4 named
'salvador':
...........................................................................
# first entry: hostname
# second entry: place of executables
#
# second entry: place of executables
#
# pvm-examples
salvador ep=/home/stolz/mobs/bin.sun4
munch ep=/home/stolz/mobs/bin.iris4d
#
## or more elegant:
##* ep=$MOBS_HOME/bin.$HOSTTYPE
##salvador
##munch
...........................................................................
```

I'm trying but linux is pretty different from Windows installation programs.
Could anyone help me please ?

You can download it from [here](http://robotics.ee.uwa.edu.au/mobs/ftp/).

Comment: Don't actually put the shell script into your console - that's `csh` code, and you (are probably) using bash. But in general, most Linux software is either package managed - see if you can find it under `yum` (or whatever Fedora uses - I'm not a Red-Hatter).

Comment: Just FYI Fedora does use yum, and to find something it'd be yum search [package name]

And to install something through the package manager it'd be yum install [package name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That software is ridiculously old.  XView hasn't been used for ages, and getting it working on a modern Linux system would be rather difficult.  PVM and OpenInventor are doable, but you'd probably have to modify the source code of the program or locate old versions of those libraries to get it to work.

I strongly suggest you take a look at some of the [more modern robotics software](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Robotics) included with Fedora, some of which has similar functionality to the software you mention.